# Laravel 9 to home page redirected

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm starting in Laravel, and I'm using Laravel 9, I'm making an API, starting for a User CRUD, when I register the user, everything it's ok, but when I got some error, example if I try to register the same email or wrong login data, the API show me the home Laravelpage, instead of to show me some error at JSON format

User registered succefully

[image: User registered succefully]

User doesn't registered succefully

[image]

I'm trying to handle the error, I would like to get some JSON messages showing what's wrong or what happened

Comment: use `Accept: application/json` in headers.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem, I was using Postman, and you need to add at header Accept = application/json

[image]